# HTML/CSS Issue - width: 100% not expanding

Tags: html, css

This is the link to the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkp9w/1/). Notice that the anchor (#nav>li>a) doesn't expand as it is supposed to when it is said:

```
#nav li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is it 'supposed to do' according to you? This question is too vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the `<a>` a block element and give some width to its parent

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block
}
#nav li a:hover {
  background: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav" class="top">
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/qkp9w/21/ Is this what you want?